# How do I add a key value pair to an existing JSON object created as a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, getjson

I am using Leaflet to produce an offline world map based on Javascript.

Here's a working JSFiddle of the example: http://codepen.io/dagmara223/pen/jydMqy

As one might see, there's a HUGE(13.000 lines) .js file with all countries in the world. A small sample being:

`"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "AFG",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [61.210817, 35.650072],
          [62.230651, 35.270664],
          [62.984662, 35.404041],
          [63.193538, 35.857166],
          [63.982896, 36.007957],
          [64.546479, 36.312073],
// Goes on and on and on...`

All is good. I have, however, implemented a functionality that will color each map based on a value(1-->100). This property is fetched from this JSON variable.

So, if the key value pair exists, it will color the given country. For example:

```
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "AFG",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "colorratio": "55" // Fetches the color ratio here!
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [61.210817, 35.650072],
          [62.230651, 35.270664],
          [62.984662, 35.404041],
          [63.193538, 35.857166],
          [63.982896, 36.007957],
    // Goes on and on ..
```

Throwing in the data statically, it definitely works. The countries are colored.

However, I am receiving this data from the backend, as objects matching the "ID" in the above JSON. For example, the data could be:

```
{
 "AFG": "25",
 "RUS": "91",
 "SWE": "67",
 "NOR": "82",
 "USA": "13"
            },
```

I am in doubt as to how I can match, for example, `"AFG":"25"` and input it as `"dataratio":"25"` in the huge `countries` variable for `Afghanistan` in this case. 
Since the country might not receive any data, it's not a given that this key value pair should be there - it should only be created if the data is there.

Comment: Looks pretty simple when using `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` array methods. What have you tried so far? (See [mcve])

Comment: @evolutionxbox Guess I could've formulated the problem way better. My concern is in terms of performance as well, since the .js file with the countries variable is extremely huge.

Comment: Hmm, I would've thought that once the JSON is parsed and in memory, then querying that object shouldn't be to bad. Can anyone confirm?